# How to make a quarter in DolphinDB database?

Tags: dolphindb

I noticed that DolphinDB database doesn't offer a data type for quarters. How can I convert a DATE column into a quarter column? For example, 2014.11.12 to 201404. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the user defined function bleow:

```
def quarter(d){
    m = month(d)
    return m/12 * 100 + ceil((m%12+1)/3.0) 
}
```